# Flutter GetX: Unexpected Route Persistence After Using Get.back()

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter project that utilizes the GetX library for managing navigation. In my setup, there is a scenario where navigating from page A to page B using Get.toNamed('B') works seamlessly, and upon triggering Get.back() from page B, it correctly returns to page A within the app.

However, the issue arises when a user back from page B to page A and then presses the back button of the browser, it navigates back to page B. Although page B was closed and finished with the Get.back() command.

I have ensured that Get.back() is appropriately used for navigation. How can I guarantee that navigating back from page A using the browser's back button does not re-open page B, but rather closes the app or navigates to the previous of stack route?

my main.dart:

```
  runApp(Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
  return GetMaterialApp(
  title: "Appname",
  initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
  getPages: AppPages.routes,
  builder: (context, child) {
    return child!;
  },
);
}));
```

---

Also I try with this code but nothing changed:

```
  GetMaterialApp(
  title: "Application",
  initialRoute: AppPages.INITIAL,
  getPages: AppPages.routes,
  smartManagement: SmartManagement.onlyBuilder,
),
```

[image: gif]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with my problem, I figured out that this problem is for my get version. I used `get: ^5.0.0-release-candidate-5` in the first step and got that problem. Now I use `get: 4.6.6` and the problem is solved but now I should fix # in URLs!
I hope the next version fixes this problem.

[image: gif]